# Loading a script from a cs file and accessing host methods, properties etc?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm just having a play with Roslyn but unsure on how to do the following.

To keep this simple, lets say I have a host program which has a method like so

```
public void DisplayMessage(string message)
{
   MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Can I then have a script file called MyScript.csx and then somewhere in the script have something like

```
void Main()
{
   Host.DisplayMessage("I am a script");
}
```

Then I have the host load the file and execute it.

If this sort of thing can't be done, is there a scripting system/engine based on c# that can do it?
These are the requirements

1. Host application can load script from a file.
2. Script file is written in c# and so can be written using VS2010 with syntax etc
3. Script file can access host public methods, properties etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you want using Roslyn.

First, create a public `Host` class that has a public `DisplayMessage` method (or use a existing class). Then create `ScriptEngine`, specifying the assembly that contains `Host` as a reference. After that, you can call `ExecuteFile()` on your file, with the `Host` object as another parameter:

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine(references: new[] { typeof(Host).Assembly });
engine.ExecuteFile("MyScript.csx", new Host());
```

The script files doesn't need any `Main()` method, and you call the method on the host object directly:

```
DisplayMessage("I am a script");
```

Comment: Ok @svick just writing DisplayMessage("I am a script"); doesn't work so how do you actually access the host's properties?

I tried adding #r "C:\MyScriptTest.exe" (assembly which executes the script), to the top of the script and do the following TestApp.MainWindow.DisplayMessage("I am a script"); But I get the "doesn't contain a definition for 'DisplayMessage'" error

Comment: You really don't need to reference it in any way, you should be able to just call it like I wrote. Are you sure you're passing an instance of `Host` to the `ExecuteFile()` method and that the method you want to call is `public`?

Comment: ok ok @svick i think I am catching on here. I was *assuming* that in order to write the script the script needed to know what the host was and what methods, properties etc it had. I was writing the script in VS and everytime I wrote something I had red line under methods and properties so I *assumed* I had the syntax wrong or something.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an [Introduction to the Roslyn scripting API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx) that covers most of what you're asking. The `ScriptEngine` type also has a `ExecuteFile` method that would be useful for what you're trying to do.

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft on the Roslyn project.